# Make the web application fit the mobile screen size

Tags: android, html, cordova

I'm using PhoneGap to create application on Android, but the size of the application page doesn't fit with the mobile screen size.

I have found this code:

```
WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
browser.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
browser.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

but I don't know where to put it, the application stops working.

Can any one help please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please follow this http://phonegap.com/install/

Comment: it works correctly, but the problem is in the size of the page, it does not fit the size of the mobile screen, i want it to be relative

Comment: do you have html file

Comment: yes i have html , css files. im using phonegap.

Comment: set meta tag :  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

Comment: nothing changed.should i edit anything in eclipes ??

Comment: your html is responsive or not please check

Comment: yes my html is responsive

Comment: where you give index.html page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be full responsive and have an application that fit the mobile screen size, the tablet screen size and the desktop web browser screen size, try to take a look to these UI frameworks made for mobile devices :

- [jQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)
- [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch)

These frameworks include meta tag and stuff to fit all screen sizes.